# I'm having issues with non-consecutive factor levels and their corresponding labels

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning, factors

I'm trying to prepare my data and I've run into a problem with mutating factors. I've done this in the past with no problem but I think the non-consecutive nature of the levels may be the issue here. The RSex mutation works perfectly yet the second one, MarStat, brings up an error message:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `MarStat`.
> i `MarStat = factor(...)`.
> x unused arguments (5, 8, 9)
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I've also tried 1:5,8,9 which brings up a different error message:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `MarStat`.
> i `MarStat = factor(...)`.
> x invalid 'labels'; length 7 should be 1 or 5
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Here's the code:

```
bsasdata <- mutate(bsasdata,
               RSex = factor(RSex,
                             levels = 1:2,
                             labels = c("Male", "Female")),
               MarStat = factor(MarStat,
                                levels = 1,2,3,4,5,8,9,
                                labels = c("Married", "Living as married",
                                           "Separated or divorced after marrying", "Widowed",
                                           "Not married", "Don't know", "Refusal")))
```

[Here's a snippet of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DG7y.png)

Comment: I think this is just a typo, you need to put a `c(1,2,etc)` around your levels argument :-D

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe it was this simple haha. Thank you so much! Can I ask how this works? I've used the factor mutate function before and didn't have to use concatenate on multiple variables. Is it because they are non-consecutive? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, in R `x:y` is shorthand for `seq(x,y)` which produces a sequence of integers from x to y. So that's a special case where you don't need a `c()`. But otherwise, if you are just inputting a vector of integers that may or may not be consecutive, you need to use `c()` to concatenate them.

Comment: Ah OK I see. Thanks so much for your help. Much appreciated!